# How do I enable certain Availability Zones in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to launch a t2.nano instance running Debian in the `us-east-1a` region, but Amazon is only allowing me to choose from between `us-west-2a`, `us-west-2b` and `us-west-2c` which are all in Oregon and too far away for my particular project.

Why can't I choose a `us-east-1a`, or even a `ap-northeast-2` availability for that matter?

Why are there only 3 options available to me?

I just launched a t2.nano instance on us-east-1a last week, so I know it's possible.

Comment: Did you ask Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in the AWS Management Console, or the AWS CLI tool, you are always working in one specific region. In your case, you're working in the us-west-2 region (Oregon).

To make the availability zone choices you want, you need to change the region you're working in.

For the AWS Management Console, choose the region by selecting it from the region menu in the top-right of the AWS Management Console.

For the AWS CLI, use the `--region` command line option to select the region you want to work with.

Once you have the correct region selected, the AZ choices you're looking for will be available.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe I have never seen that dropdown menu before. Thanks for solving my dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

In the top right of the console window, click the drop-down where it currently should say "Oregon" and choose the region you want, before starting the process to launch the instance.

Most AWS services are very strictly regional.  When you work in a region, you're dealing with resources completely isolated to that region and independent of any centralized global infrastructure.  EC2 and it's companion services (like EBS and Elastic Load Balancing) are examples of this regional design, designed for fault tolerance.  An outage in the control plane for one region should never be able to impact another.

To work with these services, you have to have the console connected to the desired region.  Oregon is the default, presumably because it has comparably low costs but is less constrained for growth than Northern Virginia (the oldest and largest by far) but the console will tend to remember your selection.

When working with EC2, you'll only see the resources in one region at a time.

Other services, like IAM, CloudFront, and Route 53 are globally distributed but managed centrally, so no regional selection is required.  Everything in these services is always visible.

S3 is a hybrid, with all the regions operationally independent for the most part, but still connected and aware of the global namespace, so you don't have to select a console region... yet you do have to select a region (in a different drop-down) when creating a bucket... but unlike the truly regional services, you get a global view of all your buckets in the console.